# How to have the same routine executed sometimes by the CPU and sometimes by the GPU with OpenACC?

Tags: openacc

I'm dealing with a routine which I want the first time to be executed by the CPU and every other time by the GPU. This routine contains the loop:

```
for (k = kb; k <= ke; k++){
for (j = jb; j <= je; j++){
for (i = ib; i <= ie; i++){
  ...
}}}
```

I tried with adding `#pragma acc loop collapse(3)` to the loop and `#pragma acc routine(routine) vector` just before the calls where I want the GPU to execute the routine. `-Minfo=accel` doesn't report any message and with Nsight-System I see that the routine is always executed by the CPU so in this way it doesn't work.
Why the compiler is reading neither of the two `#pragma`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow on to Thomas' answer, here's an example of using the "if" clause:

```
% cat test.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void compute(int * Arr, int size, int use_gpu) {

#pragma acc parallel loop copyout(Arr[:size]) if(use_gpu)
    for (int i=0; i < size; ++i) {
        Arr[i] = i;
    }
}

int main() {

   int *Arr;
   int size;
   int use_gpu;

   size=1024;
   Arr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*size);

// Run on the host
   use_gpu=0;
   compute(Arr,size,use_gpu);

// Run on the GPU
   use_gpu=1;
   compute(Arr,size,use_gpu);

   free(Arr);

}
% nvc -acc -Minfo=accel test.c
compute:
      4, Generating copyout(Arr[:size]) [if not already present]
         Generating NVIDIA GPU code
          7, #pragma acc loop gang, vector(128) /* blockIdx.x threadIdx.x */
% setenv NV_ACC_TIME 1
% a.out

Accelerator Kernel Timing data
test.c
  compute  NVIDIA  devicenum=0
    time(us): 48
    4: compute region reached 1 time
        4: kernel launched 1 time
            grid: [8]  block: [128]
             device time(us): total=5 max=5 min=5 avg=5
            elapsed time(us): total=331 max=331 min=331 avg=331
    4: data region reached 2 times
        9: data copyout transfers: 1
             device time(us): total=43 max=43 min=43 avg=43
```

I'm using nvc and set the compiler's runtime profiler (NV_ACC_TIME=1) to show that the kernel is launched only once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable OpenACC processing: `-acc` (with NVHPC tools) or `-fopenacc` (with GCC), for example, and then you need to use an OpenACC compute construct (`parallel`, `kernels`) to actually launch parallel GPU execution (plus host/device memory management, as necessary).  For example, you could call your `routine` from that compute construct, and the `routine` would annotate the loop nest with OpenACC `loop` directives, as you've mentioned, to actually make use of the GPU parallelism.

Then, to answer your actual question: the OpenACC compute constructs then support an `if` clause to specify whether *the region will execute on the current device* ("GPU") vs. *the local thread will execute the region* ("CPU").

Comment: How does this if work? You mean using a macro?

Comment: I think you'll have to provide a complete code for us to look at.